# From cronjob resource of puppet I want to append only cron job error logs to different path

Tags: cron, puppet

### cron_job.pp

```
node default {
   cron {'shutdown ':
     ensure  => 'present',
     command => ' bash  /home/azureuser/shutdown_new.sh < /home/azureuser/input.txt > /home/azureuser/cron.log 2>&1 ',
     hour    => ['*'],
     minute  => ['*/15'],
     user    => 'root',
   }

   exec {'shutdown_running_status':
     command  => 'cat /var/log/syslog | grep shutdown.sh',
     provider => shell,
   }
}
```

### shutdown.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
lsd
kk
```

When I manually execute the above manifest and script, the error logs are appended into /home/azureuser/cron.log, but when I execute through `puppet agent --test` in puppet client machine, the error logs are not appended into the same path.

Comment: By "the error logs", do you mean the output to standard out and standard error produced when the cron job managed by that manifest runs (outside the scope of the Puppet run)?

Comment: yes @Johan. How can I achieve this in puppet..?

Comment: I have intentionally  added set -e ,"lsd", "kk" in shutdown.sh file while running the script giving  errors then I want to append only error logs into "/home/azureuser/cron.logs"

Comment: Puppet's responsibility ends at installing the cron job and running the exec, and it will report on these activities in the usual place (typically syslog, but this is configurable in `puppet.conf` and via the `puppet agent` command line).  Make sure it reports that it has done this successfully, and confirm that it really has.

Comment: The error reports you want to see will occur each time the job itself is actually run.  `cron` or one of its alternative scheduling services needs to be running, or that will never happen.  Additionally, the job (probably running as root) needs to be able to write to `/home/azureuser/cron.log`, or else the job itself will fail.  This would normally be reported by mail to the job owner (again, probably `root`).

Comment: In case it was unclear, my point is that in order to answer the question, we need to know more about what actually *is* happening, not just what isn't.  Has Puppet indeed install the cron job successfully? Is a cron service actually running? What messages are being produced when cron attempts to run that job, and where?

Answer (score -1):

Suggest update to your `shutdown.sh`

**shutdown.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile
set -e
lsd
kk
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think that would help?  In particular, note well that it is intentional on the OP's part that running their version of the script should produce errors.  The question is about where the resulting error messages go.

Comment: The above suggest adding user's environment settings. Assuming script initially works for the user with her settings.

Comment: Again, then, you're missing the point.  The script is not intended to work, but rather to produce error messages, as a means to demonstrate the disposition of such messages when the cron job runs.  The question is not about getting the script to work.